# Sum variables in an array using while loop only 1 iteration per refresh PHP SQL

Tags: php, arrays, variables, while-loop, sum

Hello ***stackoverflow***, long time lurker first time asker. Anyways I am creating a project for my school and it is almost completely finished but I think I need help with the while loop. I am trying to sum the variables that are stored in the array and then output that into a useable variable that I can sum with another variable. The problem is the loop only does 1 iteration every time I refresh to page. So it will eventually get the full array but only one item at a time. Please let me know what I am going wrong, I'm sure its something dumb!

```
$bill= mysql_query("SELECT Transaction.date, Transaction.Price, Transaction.customer_customer_id, Service.cost, Service.user_id, Service.uname
FROM *.Transaction,*.Service
WHERE Transaction.customer_customer_id = Service.user_id AND Service.uname = '$uuname'");
$query_row=mysql_fetch_array($bill);
$userservice = ($query_row[cost]);
$userprice = ($query_row[Price]);

$row2=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bill))
{

    $row2[] += $row['cost'];

}
$totalservice = array_sum($row2);
```

Thanks for any help you guys may have. This one is frying my brain.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? To bring sum of all user's transactions? I see you retrieve many rows, but use only the 1st one

Comment: I am returning them so I can relate the cost and price in two different tables using Transaction.customer_customer_id = Service.user_id and Service.uname = the session name. Our database design was pretty poor in earlier steps so I have to do a lot of joins to relate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite query as

SELECT Service.user_id, Service.uname, SUM(Service.cost) as cost
FROM djqrico_hotel.Transaction LEFT JOIN djqrico_hotel.Service ON Transaction.customer_customer_id = Service.user_id
WHERE Service.uname = '$uuname' GROUP BY Service.user_id

if you want to get sum of all user's transactions.

Comment: Just noticed you using INNER JOIN in original query. You need LEFT JOIN here to avoid one record from Service being added multiple times

Comment: The query works great in SQL workbench however when I try to call it like this it returning nothing                                       ******************************************************************************************$sumservice= mysql_query("SELECT Service.user_id, Service.uname, SUM(Service.cost) as cost FROM djqrico_hotel.Transaction LEFT JOIN djqrico_hotel.Service ON Transaction.customer_customer_id = Service.user_id WHERE Service.uname = '$uuname' GROUP BY Service.user_id");
$userservice = ($sumservice[cost]);

Comment: Use this $userservice = mysql_fetch_array($sumservice);

Comment: this is giving me an ARRAY output, I really just need the total?

Comment: The value you need is in $userservice['cost']

Comment: Alex your a genius! Thanks for the help and putting up with me! Cheers! calling $userservice['cost'] is what fixed it, I was trying to call it wrong with $sumservice[cost]. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Both your SQL and your PHP make no sense.

```
FROM *.Transaction,*.Service
```

...will throw an error in MySQL, but your code doesn't check for errors. I suspect it should be:

```
FROM Transaction, Service
```

While the PHP will parse and run.....

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bill)) {
   $row2[] += $row['cost'];
}
$totalservice = array_sum($row2);
```

Is a very strange way to populate an array. Why not just....

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bill)) {
   $totalservice+=$row['cost'];
}
```

Indeed, if you are just throwing away the rest of the data, then why are you fetching it from the database?

```
SELECT SUM(Service.cost)
FROM Transaction,Service
WHERE Transaction.customer_customer_id = Service.user_id 
AND Service.uname = '$uuname'
```

In which case the join is also redundant:

```
SELECT SUM(Service.cost)
FROM Service
WHERE Service.uname = '$uuname'
```

Comment: yeah I guess your right, I didn't think of just writing another seperate query for the service cost and tried to do everything in one massive one. Sometimes simpler is probably easier. Also I edited the name of the database after the first post, I dunno always worried about security concerns even if it probably isn't one. I will try this out.

Comment: @user1898069 he wasn't suggesting writing two queries. He was saying if you **ONLY** need the sum of the cost then you can omit everything else. If you do need the other data it would be silly to write two queries

Comment: when i run your final select statement in workbench i am getting command denied to user. Also I am replacing the $uuname with a username in workbench to trick it. Any ideas? EDIT I also need the price from transaction table steve, not just cost. I am summing them both.

Comment: @user1898069 I dont know how to further help you. This answer sums up whats wrong with your query and how to fix it. If you have further issues you should consider extending your question (or if its a completely different issue perhaps opening a new question)

Comment: Sorry just an Id10T error on my part I guess. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem is the loop only does 1 iteration every time I refresh to page.*
Have you ran the query against the database and checked if it's returning more than one row?

Also, if all you want to do is sum the cost column you could do that in sql:
   `SELECT SUM(cost)[....]`

Comment: Yes when I run the query and put in a username under the last part calling for the session it returns all related rows. I will try the select sum(cost)[ What goes in here?]

Comment: @user1898069 The rest of your query. Alexander provided a more thorough example in his answer.

Comment: @user1898069 No problem :) If one of our answers helped you or is correct please mark it as an accepted answer